# Script won't write the time to file

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to write a file with the date.

I've seen a few posts, and as such was able to copy the code but instead of showing me the time, it's showing me the command

The bat file is simply

```
echo 'date -u' > server-startup-time.txt
```

When I run this file, and then look at the .txt file, I was hoping to see something like

> 00/00/0000 25:61:61

However, what I actually see is

> 'date -u'

A few more searches haven't helped - I suspect I'm typing in the wrong terms into Google.

What do I get the bat file to write the actual time/date to the file?

Comment: What operating system....

Comment: @Ramhound, updated my post. Windows Server 2012

Comment: @MikaelKjær, sadly no. When I open the text file I don't see a date, all I see is `$(date -u)`

Comment: If in a command prompt you type *date -u* what happens?

Comment: It responds with `The system cannot accept the date entered. Enter the new date: (dd-mm-yy)` @Ramhound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have used single quotes with the intent of having a command run and the output inserted into your echo statement. This only works in Windows cmd language as part of a `FOR /F` statement.
2. You have referenced the `date -u` command. This is a POSIX command, only suitable for Linux/Unix/BSD systems (or for Windows 10 using the bash shell, but that cannot be combined with cmd shell statements, as far as I know). The equivalent in Windows cmd language is `date /t` which outputs the date only, or `time /t` which outputs the time only. There is no single command that does both under Windows.
3. However the easiest way to actually achieve what you seem to want is to just use Windows psuedovariables:

   `echo %DATE% %TIME% >server-startup-time.txt`

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you for not just showing me the answer but explaining what I did wrong!